# How does one use a rails admin account outside of rails admin to edit user data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I would like to create a new controller that will allow the admin user to edit models attached to users outside of rails admin.  Here is a sample from my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admins

mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

devise_for :dealers 
devise_for :users

get "..." => "..."
etc
```

What do I need to do in both my controller and in routes.rb to make this possible?  I'm fairly new to Rails.  Thanks!  I have a limited amount of time so making a rails-admin plugin is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller check if an admin is loged in using `admin_signed_in?`, and you can also access it by `current_admin`. So you just have to place conditions checking if it's and admin to enable or not those functionalities.

EDIT:

You can have something like this in your before_filter

```
before_filter :check_authentication

private

def check_authentication
  authenticate_user! unless admin_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: What about the routes?  Do I need to specify anything special there?  Can I use a controller that is used for regular user stuff?

Comment: No, and yes. You can but I'm not sure if it's a good practice or not. But if you are in hurry then this way should be fine. Just add new actions to your controller and maybe add a before_filter to only those actions to check if an admin is loged in. And add some logic in your views to show links if there is an admin

Comment: Thanks this is all very helpful; but I still have a problem - I can't be logged in as both an admin and the user at the same time since I obviously shouldn't know the user's password.  How am I to get at his data?  I'm fine with it having to be with the "view in app" from within rails_admin but when I do that while logged in to admin, I get a you're not the valid user for this data, as I should be getting...

Comment: you must change that condition to be like `if ( user_signed_in? && @model.user_id == current_user.id) || admin_signed_in?`

Comment: Thanks again - you mean at before_filter right?  How do I modify "before_filter :authenticate_user!" to look like that?  I imagine :authenticate_user is part of Devise